# C# WebClient Timeout

Tags: c#, timeout, webclient

I have a WebClient that sends POST requests when I am pressing the button. These POSTs are done with some data inside and authentication. Here is the webclient that is declared when the application starts:

```
WebClient wc = new WebClient();
wc.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Basic " + Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("login:password")));
wc.Encoding = Encoding.UTF8;
```

Here is button code (simulates button pressed on site, all the data and headers are tracked with FireBug on Firefox):

```
wc.UploadValues("address here", new NameValueCollection()
{
  { "param1", "value1" },
  { "param2", "value2" },
  { "param3", "value3" },
  { "param4", "value4" },
  { "param5", "value5" }
 });
wc.Dispose();
```

The problem is that it works for 3-4 times and eventually it starts timing out. Even if I am catching a WebExceptionStatus.Timeout and doing a loop, it is supposed to send another POST after a t/o, but instead it tries to do so and times out again (looped over 100 times). It happens until I restart the application. I tried to add this to App.config:

```
<connectionManagement>
<add address="*" maxconnection="65535" />
</connectionManagement>
```

But it does not work. I tried to initiate a new WebClient for every POST operation separately, but it times out. Why it happens and how do I fix it? For now I just made an auto-restart of application after I finish the POST operation but it is definitely not a fix.

Comment: Suspect the server has some anti-hacking mechanism?

Comment: Well, I am not hacking into it. I am using all the same requests that Firefox does. And the legal login and password in Headers. But for some reason it only works for a 1-2 times and after that I need to restart my application.